# Const pydantic field value

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the below Pydantic model

```py
import datetime

import pydantic


class MealsService(pydantic.BaseModel):

    class MealItem(pydantic.BaseModel):
        course: str
        name: str
        quantity: int
        unitPrice: float | None

    type: str = "meals"
    items: list[MealItem]
    time: datetime.time | None


class CanapesService(pydantic.BaseModel):

    class CanapeItem(pydantic.BaseModel):
        name: str
        quantity: int
        unitPrice: float | None

    type: str = "canapes"
    items: list[CanapeItem]
    time: datetime.time | None


class Event:
    services: list[MealsService | CanapesService]
```

Given the following JSON payload

```json
{
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "canapes",
            "items": [],
            "time": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Pydantic incorrectly parses this as an instance of `MealsService`, not `CanapesService`. This makes sense, since without any of the nested field values, the two look identical. Can I specify that the "type" field ("meals" or "canapes") must be matched?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform a [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions) (available in Pydantic V2):

```py
from pydantic import Field
from typing import Annotated, Union, List


Services = Annotated[Union[MealsService, CanapesService], Field(discriminator='type')]


class Event(pydantic.BaseModel):
    services: List[Services]
```

As an aside, you will need to convert the value of `type` to `Literal` as such -> `type: Literal['meals'] = "meals"`

> Further reading: [Pydantic for Experts: Discriminated Unions in Pydantic V2](https://blog.det.life/pydantic-for-experts-discriminated-unions-in-pydantic-v2-2d9ca965b22f)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with the help of Descriminated unions.

```
from typing import Literal, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError


class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog']
    barks: float


class Lizard(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['reptile', 'lizard']
    scales: bool


class Model(BaseModel):
    pet: Union[Cat, Dog, Lizard] = Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')
    n: int


print(Model(pet={'pet_type': 'dog', 'barks': 3.14}, n=1))
#> pet=Dog(pet_type='dog', barks=3.14) n=1
try:
    Model(pet={'pet_type': 'dog'}, n=1)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
    """
    1 validation error for Model
    pet.dog.barks
      Field required [type=missing, input_value={'pet_type': 'dog'}, input_type=dict]
    """
```

More info: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-str-discriminators